# HBase issue : GC Pauses Stoping Region Servers

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, ycsb

I have a following Hardware configuration for my 6 Node Hbase Cluster (1 Master - 5 Slaves)

Configuration of Each Node

2.4Ghz, 48 Core Intel CPU

256GB RAM

1Gb/ps Network Connectivity

30 x SSD Disks (JBOD Setup)

OS: RHEL 6.6

Hbase Version:1.2.0

CDH Distribution: 5.7.0

I am doing YCSB testing, when I reached to 100 million records, regionserver aborted saying following issues :

```
Detected pause in JVM or host machine (eg GC): pause of approximately 3092ms
GC pool 'ParNew' had collection(s): count=1 time=0ms
GC pool 'ConcurrentMarkSweep' had collection(s): count=1 time=3170ms
```

Also

```
(responseTooSlow): {"processingtimems":22647,"call":"Get(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$GetRequest)"
```

heap size for region server given as 16GB ( tried with 32GB),

It seems most of the time is going in collecting garbage and hence my YCSB performance is 3 ops/sec or 0 ops/sec it showing. I followed GC tuning guides but couldn't help a lot. Can anyone suggest what could be done ?????

Comment: uhm .... your testing software is aborting because the GC pauses? Thats ... a pretty solid indicator for faulty software design - the GC is nigh-irrelevant as long as you dont keep hitting its overhead limits; and thats a pretty complicated thing to do, usually the software is in an infinite cycle of object-creation until that happens.

Comment: So what could be done in that case ? So tuning won't work here ?? Is this a software limitations ?